# lstm autoencoder prediction always starts with zero

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am trying to build an LSTM autoencoder to find anomalies in a set of signals. The autoencoder seems to work well except at the beginning of curves. At he beginning, all the reconstructed curves start around zero. Actually zero here is the mean of each curve as I standardized them. Look at this image

[An example of original vs reconstructed curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2jQe.png)

And it happens for all curves. The training curves look like this

[Training curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztp2W.png)

What am I missing here?

The autoencoder is built using Keras as follows

```
input_dim = 1
latent_dim = 50
array_length = lstm_df.shape[1]

inputs = Input(shape=(array_length, input_dim))
# encoding
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True )(inputs)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True, activation='linear'(encoded)
# I also tried the default activation (tanh) here

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
sequence_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')
# I also tried 'adam' optimizer

# And trained as follows

epochs = 80
history = sequence_autoencoder.fit(lstm_df.values.reshape(lstm_df.shape[0], array_length, input_dim), 
                                   lstm_df.values.reshape(lstm_df.shape[0], array_length, input_dim),
                                   verbose=True,
                                   epochs=epochs,
                                   batch_size=32,
                                   shuffle=True)
# Prediction
prediction = sequence_autoencoder.predict(test.values.reshape(test.shape[0], array_length, input_dim))
mse = np.power(test.values - prediction.reshape(test.shape), 2).mean(1)
error_df = pd.DataFrame({'reconstruction error': -mse.ravel()}, index=test.index)
# I am inverting the mse to stick to the convention, the smaller the more outlier 

outliers_fraction = .2

no_of_anomalies = int(len(error_df) * outliers_fraction)
anomolus_ids = error_df.sort_values('reconstruction error').head(no_of_anomalies).index
```

train and test data are downloaded from here
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/tree/master/smalldata/anomaly

ecg_discord_train.csv and ecg_discord_test.csv